# simple ping function returns "Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a simple ping function and get a result of either 0 or 1.
But if this function below i keep getting an access denied error, i've tried with several web sites and i always get the same error.

```
from os import *

hostname = "localhost"
status = system("ping -c " + hostname)

if status == 1:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Can you run that command at the prompt?

Comment: Have you tried Googling your error message? Seems pretty clear to me...

Comment: This has nothing to do with python. And its going to be operating system specific also. On linux, `-c` is for packet count. On windows its not valid.

Comment: I have UAC disable and i'm the administrator, i can run any command without problem, even if i run "ping www.google.com" i don't get an error, but when i add the -c switch i do get an error.

Comment: UAC, ..., so Windows? Its not valid on my win7. What does `-c` mean? UAC only covers some machine privileges, admin rights may also be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

```
import subprocess

hostname = "localhost"
cmd = "ping -n 1 " + hostname
status = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
if status[0] == 0:
    print ("yes")
else:
    print ("no")
```

Note: I ran the script on Windows. Hence `-n` option instead of `-c` for specifying the count.

Comment: For me it works. response = os.system('ping -n 1 ' + m.ip) if response == 0: print("ok")

Answer (score 1):

the command needs to be run like administrator. For example if you start your Python shell by right click and "Run like administrator" it should work.

This is tested on windows, but I believe it will be similar on Linux, just you will have to run it like root. I am not much experienced with Linux so can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When pinging with `-c` option, you have to specify the number of pings. When you `ping <somehost>` in windows, default 4 packets will send (and recieve, unless there is problem in connection, or you break the process). But in linux systems it pings infinitely. Honestly I don't know the count, I just <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and break the process after enough count of packets transmitted and recieved:)

```
$ ping -c 2 google.com
PING google.com (62.212.252.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.212.252.123: icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=30.8 ms
64 bytes from 62.212.252.123: icmp_req=2 ttl=58 time=32.6 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 30.860/31.761/32.663/0.918 ms
```

as a python script

```
>>> import os
>>> status = os.system("ping -c 2 google.com")
PING google.com (62.212.252.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cache.google.com (62.212.252.45): icmp_req=1 ttl=58 time=31.6 ms
64 bytes from cache.google.com (62.212.252.45): icmp_req=2 ttl=58 time=31.6 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 31.622/31.632/31.642/0.010 ms
>>>
```

or your case

```
    >>> host = "localhost"
    >>> status = os.system("ping -c 2 "+ host)
    PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
    64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms

    --- localhost ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.046/0.053/0.009 ms
```

if you don't specify counts,

```
$ ping -c google.com
ping: bad number of packets to transmit.
```

or,

```
>>> os.system("ping -c google.com")
ping: bad number of packets to transmit.
512
```

Comment: How do you know OP is running linux? OP is getting a different error message than what you show... isn't that a good indication that OP's `-c` isn't a count?

Comment: i understand you, but `ping -c` is only available on unix like systems for specifying number of packets to transmit. in windows there is no such option (maybe `-r`, i don't remember), and it will spit out an error message (bad option). i think he has done a mistake and will correct it. actually the possibility of he has done a mistake, is higher than he is using any other system that UNIX likes, Windows and else :) and more important, pinging doesn't require adminstrative privileges.

Comment: I am using windows, there is a -c command for ping " -c compartment Routing compartment identifier." from ping /?, i'm not sure about what it does exactly, i just used something i found online, at the time i didn't think about it being a linux command.
But it should work on windows as well.

Comment: @AlexZel what is your windows version? I checked my XP machine, also Win7 SP1 on virtualbox, no "-c" options seems available to me.